# Function insert new.values + values from a1.t1, on postgresql

Tags: postgresql, function, insert

I have  2 tables 
subjects (sub_id, sub_title, dep_id...)
departments (dep_id, dep_name...)

My function have to record a new subject ('maths'), and the dep_id corresponding (where dep_name = sciences) and then, to return a sub_id

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_sujet (param_title varchar, dep_name varchar)
RETURNS integer AS $$
INSERT INTO sujets (suj_id, suj_title, dep_id) 

SELECT NEW.dep_id FROM departements 
WHERE d.dep_name=$3
RETURNING suj_id, NEW;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plgsql' VOLATILE;
```

I know this but don t understand how to combine this function with an insert new value

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_insert (p_r1, p_r2)
RETURNS integer AS $$
INSERT INTO table (r1, r2) VALUES ($1, $2)
RETURNING r1_id;
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql' VOLATILE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_insert (p_r1, p_r2)
RETURNS integer AS $$
INSERT INTO table (r1, r2) VALUES ($1, (SELECT r2 INTO .. AS ... =$2)
RETURNING r1_id;
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql' VOLATILE;
```

Better to make a sub query.